# Are there languages with both the singulative and the main verb 'have'?

Tags: linguistic-typology, list-of-languages

Celtic and Arabic both exhibit singulative forms and both lack the verb 'have'.  I would like to know whether there are are singulative languages that have the main verb 'have'.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you want to link these two particular features. But then, why not?

Comment: I am working on a hypothesis under which there could be a relationship, but if there is a singulative language with 'have' I can cut the inquiry short.

Comment: The problem is that there are lot of languages that do not have the verb "to have", but have no singulatives either.

Comment: Also, many languages have significantly demoted *to have* (eg Russian) so it is not required and not used in many constructions, but technically still have it for emphatic purposes and in calcified phrases.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer But there are also languages lacking "to have" as a verb completely.

Comment: The richest collection of data regarding possessive constructions is L. Stassen's book: https://books.google.it/books?id=5JESDAAAQBAJ&dq=predicative+possessive+construction&hl=it&source=gbs_navlinks_s

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the reference to Stassen, I believe I have identified several languages in which these features co-exist: Kanuri, Shilluk, Krongo, Nobiin, Tirmaga and Nandi. Thanks to all.